# Where to get CoreTelephony.framework for iOS 5

Tags: ios, frameworks, mixpanel

**Context**

I'm trying to add the CoreTelephony.framework so I can use mixpanel analytics in my iOS app. My app is targeted at iOS 5.1+. I'm running XcodeVersion 4.6.3. I have the iOS 5.1 simulator installed.

When I click the "Build Phases" and then the section "Link Binary With Libraries" and click the plus to add a library. I get this dialog box:

[image]

**Quesitons**

- Does the fact that all these frameworks are in the "iOS 6.1" folder mean they will only run on iOS 6.1?
- How would I add the CoreTelephony.framework so it will run on iOS 5.1 or greater?

Comment: Do you have a solid reason for continuing to support 5.1?

Comment: Well it hasn't really caused much if any issue so far, the app is already live. I believe around 10% of general pop has generation younger than 6.0, so we want to continue to support to a) capture that revenue b) not upset people only on 5.0

Comment: FYI - the list shown under `iOS 6.1` is the list of frameworks and libraries available as of iOS 6.1. Most have been available longer. If you pick a framework that was added after iOS 5.1 then your app needs to be coded properly to avoid referencing any symbols in the framework when your app is running on a device with a version of iOS prior to the introduction of the framework. You should also mark the framework as "option" instead of the default "required". And as always, thoroughly test your app on devices which each version of iOS that your app supports.

Comment: But there is no way in this dialogue box to know what framework was created when, right? You have to look it up in reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CoreTelephony has been available since iOS4. You can simply add it to your project from Build Phases even though it is listed under iOS6.1. It will still build and run fine under iOS5.1.